# Join column2 when the content of column1 is the same

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table like this:

```
CODE   EMPLOYEE   HOURS
1      PER_1      1
5      PER_2      2
5      PER_1      1
5      PER_1      3
3      PER_3      1
```

And I need to join columns with the same CODE into one, but with all EMPLOYEES and HOURS in that column. The result I want would be like this:

```
CODE   EMPLOYEE               HOURS
1      PER_1                  1
5      PER_2, PER_1, PER_1    2, 1, 3
3      PER_1                  1
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `JOIN`, You have to use [**STUFF**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) in following:

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE(Code INT, Employee NVARCHAR(40), Hours INT)
INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES
(1     ,'PER_1',      1),
(5     ,'PER_2',      2),
(5     ,'PER_1',      1),
(5     ,'PER_1',      3),
(3     ,'PER_3',      1)
```

---

**QUERY**

```
SELECT  Code
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(Employee AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]    
               FROM @Tbl 
               WHERE Code = t.Code
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
              .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,' ') Employee
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(Hours AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]       
               FROM @Tbl 
               WHERE Code = t.Code
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
              .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,' ') Hours
FROM @Tbl t
GROUP BY Code
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
Code      Employee                Hours
1         PER_1                   1
3         PER_3                   1
5         PER_2, PER_1, PER_1     2, 1, 3
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much, worked perfectly!
Thanks also to lad2025 for answering!

Answer (score 0):

For Concatentation use [XML + STUFF trick](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/):

```
SELECT [code]
   ,[employee] =  STUFF( (SELECT ',' + t1.Employee
                          FROM tab t1
                          WHERE t.[code] = t1.[code]
                          FOR XML PATH('')), 
                         1, 1, '')
   ,[hours] = STUFF( (SELECT ',' + t1.Hours 
                      FROM tab t1
                      WHERE t.[code] = t1.[code]
                      FOR XML PATH('')), 
                      1, 1, '')
FROM tab t
GROUP BY [code]
```